# How can I convert an HTML page to an image or PDF and then convert it to byte array?

Tags: java

How can I convert an HTML page to an image or PDF and then convert it to byte array?

Answer (score 1):

I've used PrinceXML as a tool to convert from html to PDF before, it worked excellently.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In the way of pdf, do you just want to embed the image or should it be text? If text, it's very individual. And Image to Bytearray have a look at the ImageIO class of java.

To convert html to pdf this link maybe helpful: 
http://kac-ani.xt.pl/en/node/27

Comment: i want to embed an image and also text in the PDF.

Comment: do you have a block code that convert HTML (that containes an image and text) to PDF?

Comment: added a link to my answer. Have a look